# how to retrieve data from particular rows of every table of mysql in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables as h_basic, h_amenities and h_images with common column u_name. there are two php pages named product-list and product-review. I want to fetch the details of a particular product on product-review page when I click on the button of that product on product-list page.

I have the code that retrieves a single row from a single table, but i want to retrieve particular rows of all three tables and i also want to take u_name as primary not id since id is varying in all the tables.

```html
<?php
    $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : "0";
    $sql = ("SELECT h_basic.*, h_images.* FROM h_basic JOIN h_images WHERE h_basic.id = h_images.id");
    $result = mysql_query("$sql");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
   echo $row['h_name']; echo $row['h_state'];
?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['h_image01'];?>"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['h_image02'];?>"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['h_image03'];?>"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['h_image04'];?>">
<?php }?>
```

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use whatever fields do match as the `ON` condition of a `JOIN`

```
SELECT B.*, I.*, A.*
FROM h_basic B
LEFT JOIN h_images I ON B.u_name = I.u_name
LEFT JOIN h_amenities A IN B.u_name = A.u_name
```

You would need to add a `WHERE` clause to get a specific name

Notice this will go faster if you have an index on each table for the joining fields

Comment: but sir, as u can see in those image ids are different. so i can't take id as base. i wanna take u_name instead.

Comment: Just use whatever fields DO match as a JOIN condition. Notice this will go faster if you have an index on the joining fields

Comment: I edited my code to this..: $id = $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : "0";
    $sql = "SELECT B.*,A.*, I.* FROM h_basic AS B LEFT JOIN h_amenities AS A ON B.u_name = A.u_name LEFT JOIN h_images AS I ON B.u_name = I.u_name WHERE id =".$id; But still getting error. sir, i'm a beginner.. would u like to edit it once?